# Migration exception - could not create unique index

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, fluent-migrator

I have a schema for customer is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.customer
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    id_number integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(128),
    cust_group uuid NOT NULL,
    card_discount_group smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1'::integer,
    invoice_address uuid,

    CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to set id_number as unique. I am using fluent migrator and using the following code structure.

```
    public override void Down()
    {
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        Execute.Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.customer ADD CONSTRAINT id_number_unique UNIQUE (id_number);");
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred executing the following sql:
> ALTER TABLE dbo.customer ADD CONSTRAINT id_number_unique UNIQUE (id_number);
> The error was 23505: could not create unique index "id_number_unique"

I am not sure what do I have to do. Any suggestion how can I fix the error?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Postgresql? The dbo schema is typically used in MS SQL Server environments.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you have duplicate values in the column `id_number`. You need to delete those duplicates before you can create the unique index

Comment: Hei. Thank you very much. You are right.  @a_horse_with_no_name